# How to process files with file names in records from Kafka using JavaSparkContext?

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-kafka, spark-streaming

In my application, there is Web UI application sending the file path after completing the file upload process to Kafka.

I have a Spark Streaming application that pulls messages from Kafka using `JavaSparkContext` and `JavaPairInputDStream` (so it receives the file path, but there could also be multiple file paths).

I have to process the files in parallel and need to send the result to another kafka stream:

```
SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("Task1").setMaster("local[*]");
    sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    JavaStreamingContext ssc = new JavaStreamingContext(sc, new Duration(2000));

    Map<String, String> kafkaParams = new HashMap<>();
    kafkaParams.put("metadata.broker.list", "localhost:9092");
    Set<String> topics = Collections.singleton("topic1");

    JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> directKafkaStream = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(ssc, String.class,
            String.class, StringDecoder.class, StringDecoder.class, kafkaParams, topics);

    directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(rdd -> {

        rdd.collect().forEach((t) -> {
            sendMessage(sc, t._2());
        });
    });

    ssc.start();
    ssc.awaitTermination();
```

`sendMessage` will send the data inside the file.

In the above implementation I am using JavaSparkContext inside the foreachRDD method which is not the best practice. I want to process the file in parallel.

Comment: @JacekLaskowski I thnik that this is just one of many problems in this code and question. Currently question is very broad and unclear that is needed or what's not clear for the author

Answer (score 2):

I'd create a function `sendMessage` that would be a pure Kafka producer (with no dependency on Spark, esp. `JavaSparkContext`) that would send a message to a Kafka topic or take an iterator of all the messages to send out.

See the [official documentation of Apache Kafka](http://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#gettingStarted).

With the pure Kafka producer as `sendMessage` I'd do the following in Spark Streaming's transformation (the comments inline should give you some hints as to what happens at every line):

```
def sendMessage(message: String) = {
  println(s"Sending $message to Kafka")
}
dstream.map(_.value).foreachRDD { rdd =>
  println(s"Received rdd: $rdd with ${rdd.count()} records")
  // take paths from RDD that contains Kafka records with the file names
  val files = rdd.collect()
  files.foreach { f =>
    // read a file `f` using Spark Core's RDD API
    rdd.sparkContext.textFile(f).map { line =>
      // do something with line
      // this is the place for a pure Spark transformation
      // it's as if you were outside Spark Streaming
      println(line)
      line
    }.foreachPartition { linesAfterProcessingPerPartition =>
      // send lines to Kafka
      // they have been processed using Spark
      linesAfterProcessingPerPartition.foreach { line =>
        sendMessage(message = line)
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure the code could get even clearer, but that would be Scala and you use Java so I'll stop here.

---

I'd strongly recommend using [Spark SQL's Structured Streaming](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html) as that soon will replace Spark Streaming and become the streaming API in Spark.

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
directKafkaStream.foreachRDD(new VoidFunction<JavaRDD<String>>() {
    public void call(JavaRDD<String> stringJavaRDD) throws Exception {
        stringJavaRDD.foreachPartition(new VoidFunction<Iterator<String>>() {
            public void call(Iterator<String> stringIterator) throws Exception {
                sendMessage(stringIterator);
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: What about the SparkContext for `sendMessage`?